# How to cancel the pop up from the App Store in In App Purchase?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I want to cancel the `SKRefreshReceiptRequest` on the click of `Cancel` button of generated pop up from the App Store and it *should never pop up again* after it is cancelled for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The IAP-related alerts are system-generated. The only way to prevent them is to *both* not do anything that triggers them and to guarantee that any actions that do generate them cleanly complete.

In other words, if you use IAP, you can minimize them but not eliminate them.

One thing to note though is that sandbox testing can generate many more of the alerts than production use will.